# Two particle collision - excited particle emits photon absorbed by the other particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

[image]

**Part (a)**

Doing everything in the lab frame:
4-vector before collision: $(Mc,0)$

Let $E$ be energy of photon emitted, p be momentum of de-excited particle.
4-vector after collision: $(\frac{E1}{c},−p)+(\frac{E}{c},\frac{E}{c})$

By conservation of momentum and energy:

$$ Mc^2 = E + E_1$$
$$ E = pc$$

Solving gives:
$$ E = \frac{M^2 - m^2}{2M} c^2 $$

**Part (b)**

Before collision in the rest frame of particle 1:
4-vector before collision: $(Mc,0) + (\gamma_r mc, \gamma_r m \vec{v_r})$

After collision in the rest frame of particle 2:
4-vector after collision: $(\gamma_r' mc, \gamma_r' m \vec{v_r'}) + (Mc,0)$

Invariance of 4 vector gives:
$$ (Mc + \gamma_r mc)^2 - (\gamma_r m \vec{v_r})^2 = (Mc + \gamma_r' mc)^2 - (\gamma_r' m \vec{v_r'})^2 $$

The only meaningful result here is $\gamma_r = \gamma_r'$ and the relative velocities in the frame of particle 2 reverses upon absorption, i.e. $v_r = v_r'$.

How do I find an expression for $v_r$ without knowing their initial speeds?

Comment: You are asked to provide the result "in terms of their velocity". So you say velocity = $v$ and keep going.

Comment: @Floris I'm supposed to find the relative speed $v_r$ in terms of $m$ and $M$.